# reverse function of require/include

Tags: php

Is there any function that reverts a require/require_once/include/include_once?

For instance in script A I need to require a script B wich has common functions witch other script C and I don't know if previously C was required or not. So I would like to "clean" script C from memory before loading B preventing duplicated functions.

Comment: No,No,No but you can override your previously defined functionality.

Comment: are your defining only functions in a file ? You can define a class in each file that contains functions. Like a helper class with static methods.

Comment: wow, that's a good idea too, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not - and should not do that. Instead use [`require_once`](https://www.php.net/require_once) - it will be safe for such operations. Note, that after inclusion your context will be changed - so no way to "reverse" it back could be applied.

If you want to override some functionality - you can always do that, it will work normally. And you should check things before declaring them:

- [`function_exists()`](https://www.php.net/function_exists) for functions
- [`class_exists()`](https://www.php.net/class_exists) for classes
- (optional) [`defined()`](https://www.php.net/defined) for constants

Comment: require_once would load C and I would finish with duplicated functions, wouldn't?

Comment: require_once will safely include a file (i.e. no duplicates would be allowed). However, to override some functionality - it will be a good idea to use require_once since you'll be sure that you will not re-define some previously declared things

Comment: Didn't know that, I thougth it only checked that the same file wasn't included. thanks

Comment: `require_once` will still allow duplicates if same function is defined in two different files, which appears t be the case in this question. `function_exists` can be added to this to solidify this solution.

Comment: ty Hanky Panky for the clarification

Comment: also isset() for variables. by the way

Answer (score 3):

Not that I'm aware of.

Honestly, my recommendation (assuming you are "cleaning" up some code) would be to abstract out the common functions of script B and script C into another script D and use require_once/include_once in both script B and C.

Answer (score 2):

That's not how it works. You can however prevent your function library from function naming conflicts using :

```
if (!function_exists('myfunction')) {
    function myfunction($param) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

That is, if you are not already using require_once / include_once everywhere (and you should).

Comment: notice that B and C are diferent but with some functions with the same name. require_once/include_once would load both. BTW, I like your solution, thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could namespace your files to prevent collisions:

```
<?php

namespace Foo {
    function test() {
        return __NAMESPACE__ . '::' . __FUNCTION__;
    }
}

namespace Bar {
    function test() {
        return __NAMESPACE__ . '::' . __FUNCTION__;
    }
}

namespace Baz {
  var_dump(array(
      \Foo\test(),
      \Bar\test(),    
  ));
}
```

https://eval.in/82425